# cocoa touch: rand() returning the same string

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, random, rubiks-cube

Here's my code:

```
-(void)randommoves
{

NSArray *possiblemoves =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"R ",@"R' ",@"L ",@"L' ",@"B ",@"B' ",@"F ",@"F' ",@"U ",@"U' ",@"D ",@"D' ", nil];
NSMutableString *finalmoves = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
finalmoves = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0]; 
[finalmoves retain];
int i = 0;
for (i=0; i<20; i++) {
    int r = rand() % 13;
    NSString *string = [possiblemoves objectAtIndex:r];
    [finalmoves appendString:string];
}
NSLog(@"%@",finalmoves);
[finalmoves release];
}
```

And every time I run it I get the EXACT same string "D' B B' D L' D' F' L' B' U' D D D' L' U R B F D' B' "

What I want it to do is give me a new move set every time I run it

I've ran this at least 30 times to make sure that it wasn't a fluke, and that it really WAS returning the same string, and sure enough, it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to make sure you seed your random number generator first.

before entering your loop do:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Comment: thanks, it worked (and also uncovered a little bug I had in int r = rand() % 13; where I forgot to count for 0)

Answer (score 1):

Note that you are creating `finalMoves` twice. Once with `[[NSMutableString alloc] init]` and then again with `[NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:0]`. This means you are leaking memory.

How about cleaning up this code like this:

```
static NSArray* sPossibleMoves = nil;

+ (void) initialize
{
    sPossibleMoves = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"R ",@"R' ",@"L ",@"L' ",@"B ",@"B' ",@"F ",
        @"F' ",@"U ",@"U' ",@"D ",@"D' ", nil] retain];
}

- (void) randomMoves
{
    NSMutableString* finalmoves = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: 20];
    if (finalMoves != nil) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            [finalMoves appendString: [sPossibleMoves objectAtIndex:
                (rand() % [sPossibleMoves count])]];
        }
        NSLog(@"%@",finalmoves);
    }
}
```

Assuming that you will call this often, it makes sense to keep the possible moves around in a global (because Objective-C lacks class variables)

Comment: thanks a bunch!  I just had to add the srand(time(NULL)); to it and it worked!  That's much better then what I was going to do (believe me, that code that I posted above would never make it into the shipping application)