# Creating and managing two independent random number sequences

Tags: iphone, objective-c, srand

I'm having trouble generating two independent random sequences using the rand and srand functions. The details are below, any help would be most appreciated.

I'm working on a puzzle game for the iPhone, and usually for the random number generation I use the arc4 function. However for the multiplayer mode I want both players to have the same pieces throughout the game, and the only way I can control it is to have two repeatable random sequences. If I then send the seeds to the other device, the games will be identical. However when I use rand and srand and try to switch to the other seed, the sequence starts from scratch, I somehow have to initialize two independent sequences generated with a seed.

Thank you for your responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the suggestions, this is how I implemented the whole thing. I created a singleton class with 2 instance variables - seed1 and seed2 - anytime I want to get a number from the first generator I use the method generator1, same for generator2 method. The seed1/2 is instantly set to a newly generated number every time so I can just continue where I left off. In conlusion, Josh Caswell gave me all the information I needed. Check out the code if you ever need something like this. The object inits with seeds 1 and 1 but during the game they get replaced with some other numbers that both devices share.

```
@implementation RandomNumberGenerator

@synthesize seed1,seed2;

static RandomNumberGenerator *sharedGenerator = nil;

+(RandomNumberGenerator *) sharedInstance
{
if(!sharedGenerator) {
    sharedGenerator = [[RandomNumberGenerator alloc] initWithSeed1:1 andSeed2:1];
}

return sharedGenerator;
}

-(id) initWithSeed1:(int) seedOne andSeed2:(int) seedTwo{
self = [super init];
if (self)
{
    seed1 = seedOne;
    seed2 = seedTwo;
}
return self;
}

-(int) generator1{
srand(seed1);
int j = rand();
seed1 = j;
return abs(j);

}

-(int) generator2 {
srand(seed2);
int k = rand();
seed2 = k;
return abs(k);
}

-(int) giveRandom {
//return abs(arc4random());
return abs(arc4random());
}


@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Cryptographically bad PRNGs like `rand()` operate by feeding the previous result back into a certain mathematical procedure.

In order to continue a sequence from where it left off, all you have to do is store the last-generated number and use it as the seed:

```
srand(time(0));
int player1_rand_num = rand();
NSLog(@"Player 1: %d, %d, %d", rand(), rand(), rand());
srand(7);
int player2_rand_num = rand();
NSLog(@"Player 2: %d, %d, %d", rand(), rand(), rand());

// Re-seed Player 1 sequence
srand(player1_rand_num);
// Displays the same "random" numbers as the first NSLog
NSLog(@"Player 1 again: %ld, %ld, %ld", rand(), rand(), rand());
// and so on...
```

The `random()` function generates better random numbers, and has a separate pair of functions, `initstate()` and `setstate()` which will give you the state of the generator. You can store the state and pass it into `setstate()` to resume the sequence from where you left off. I direct you to [`man 3 random`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/random.3.html) for the details.

Comment: This can't possibly be true.  Otherwise anybody would be able to recreate your sequence simply by seeding with one of the outputs.  This would open up the door to massive security holes in encryption systems.  I even tried running your code, and came up with different values after reseeding.

Comment: @Tim: What I said is true of `rand()`, which, yes, is exactly why you don't use it for cryptography. I habitually swapped the OP's use of `rand()` for the better (but still not cryptographically great) `random()`, neglecting the fact that it has separate `initstate()` and `setstate()` functions to do what I'm talking about.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that worked for the old rand().  I've always avoided it like the plague.

Comment: Off-topic, but it is this deficiency that make `rand()` perfect for unit tests which don't involve cryptography.

Answer (score 1):

First off, as others have pointed out already, you should use `random()` instead of `rand()`. Secondly, while your singleton approach may work for you, you could solve your problem more easily and IMHO more elgantly by using `setstate(3)`. See [Use of setstate(3) doesn't produce expected sequence of random numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029134/use-of-setstate3-doesnt-produce-expected-sequence-of-random-numbers) for an example on how to switch between two random number states.

Comment: Cool, although the problem has been solved for a while, I will definitely take a look at setstate. For the implementation I used a singleton (which is totally unnecessary looking back), it will work nonetheless when used as an instance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you **seed your random number generator**?

```
srand( myIdenticalSeedValueForBothPartners );
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2215737/cocoa-touch-rand-returning-the-same-string) or [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/) [C++ reference].

In case you don't need to call rand() many thousand times:

```
int nthRandBasedOnSeed( int seed, int count ) {

   srand( seed );

   int result;
   while( 0 < count-- ) {

     result = rand();

   }

   return result;

}
```

Comment: yes, I seed random generator with srand, lets assume I seed it with 1 - i.e srand(1) and I want my other generator to have seed 2- srand(2), what I'm trying to achieve is to be able to switch between seed 1 and seed 2 as many times as I want during the game, and continue both of them where it left of. However when you change the seed via srand() and send a rand(), it starts the sequence from scratch, I somehow wish to continue from where it left off.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you might consider sending with the seed a "count". This count would simply indicate where in the seeded-series you are and would get incretented each time you generate a random number with that seed. This approach gives you the flexibility of using any random generator you like and keeps communication to a minimum.

```
int playerSeed = 12345;
int playerRndCount = 0;

int generateRandomNumber() {
    playerRndCount++;
    return rand();
}

void synchSeed(seed, count) {
    srand(seed);
    for (int i=0;  i<count;  i++)
        generateRandumNumber();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Some random number generator libraries allow you to save the state of the generator.  This way, you can restore it later, and continue with a sequence already in progress.  One I know of is called RandomLib, and it can be found on SourceForge.

Another option is save the seed, and count how many times you've pulled a value from the generator after seeding.  Later on when you want to continue, reseed with the original seed, and pull off the same quantity.  This probably isn't the best method, but should work fine if not done a lot.

Comment: thank you this looks good, any idea if I still will be submit the app if I use a 3rd party library like this?

Comment: It should be ok, the license is pretty open: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/MIT