# Does srand() reproduce results between iOS devices?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8, prng

I want to shuffle a hard-coded list of values, and be able to get the same result across devices. So, I thought that instead of sending the shuffled list's values, send only a number to initialize `rand()`.

Would it work? Do `srand()` and `rand()` work the same across devices (including the simulator?)

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: This will of course work for the same implementation of the PRNG; the only question would be whether it changes/has changed between system (stdlib) versions, which I don't know how to check. Interesting question.

Comment: A question I asked more than 3 years ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343421/creating-and-managing-two-independent-random-number-sequences